# How to capture a variable query string, then append it to all URLs in a Wordpress site

Tags: wp-query, javascript, urls

I have a site in which people will be sent there with various promo code query strings (that will change all the time), i.e., www.example.com/?source=emailad

How would I capture the query string, then append it on to all URLs in the site.

I have searched for an hour, and have found how to capture a query string, and also how to append a known value onto an href, but not how to capture an unknown string and append it on. I need to just capture everything from the ? on and append it to a URL, regardless of what the string is.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you referring to using `$_GET`? This global array stores things in a query string as an array. This sounds more of a PHP question than WordPress question.

Comment: It's not from a form, it is just to track the source of a promotion email - so I basically need to grab the ? and anything after it and add that to all the url's on the site.

Comment: It's the same thing, you'll find it in `$_GET`. Form submission or regular link anything `?foo=bar` will be found in the global get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$_GET` global stores all query string entries, you should be able to use that. As for appending them to URLs, you could add a hook to the `post_content` filter to update any links in the post/page content, as well as hooks on the various permalink filters (e.g. `page_link`, `post_link`, etc.).

Personally, the filters approach will take a lot of work to make sure you cover all links on the site. I suggest instead you use javascript to update them all on page load. Here's how you could do it in jQuery

```
$('a[href]').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    if(href.indexOf('?') !== -1){
        // Query string exists, append current query string
        href += '&' + location.search.replace(/^\?/, '');
    }else{
        // No query string yet, add it
        href += location.search;
    }

    $(this).attr('href', href);
});
```

The `location.search` contains the query string of the page. The function will update ANY links it finds so you may want to refine it to only cover links that are relative to your site (test if `this.href` starts with your site's home url.

If you have any links that may be created after page load, you'll need to rework it into a click event that replaces the `href` attribute before it fires.

I'm not sure why you need to do this, but depending on the purpose it may be simpler to just have some custom code that stores data in their `$_SESSION` so that they're remembered as having come to the site via the email, without having the query string preserved everywhere.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['source'])){
    $_SESSION['was_referred'] = true;
}
if(isset($_SESSION['was_referred'])){
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much - so would I need to use $_Get and the JQuery you provided, or just the JQuery. If I do need to use $_Get, how would I do that? Thanks again!

Comment: I added the JS above, it didn't seem to change the links, I will keep checking it, thanks for the help.

Comment: You may need to mess around with the code a bit (check the console in case of errors). I did a quick test and it does work.

Oh, and yes if you're using jQuery then you don't need to bother with any PHP code; it was a one or the other option.

Comment: This is what I get in the console - TypeError: $ is not a function
 

$('a[href]').each(function(){

Comment: Ah, you'll have to wrap that all in this: `jQuery(function($){ /* your code in here */ });` (and of course make sure jQuery is actually loaded on the page.